# How to get maximum possible window size when creating window in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to get the maximum possible height and width of a window being created (window is not maximized first). How to do it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  And, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I window can be resized to be bigger than the screen, so there is no real maximum size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) with `SM_CXSCREEN` and `SM_CYSCREEN`. This is the width and height off your primary display monitor.

Another way would be to determine the desktop workarea size:

```
CRect rectWorkArea;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA,0,&rectWorkArea,0);
```

Or to determine the size of the work area of a specific monitor were your window exists

```
CRect rectWorkArea;
MONITORINFO mi;
mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
::GetMonitorInfo(::MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), &mi);
rectWorkArea = mi.rcWork;
```

`MONITORINFO` also contains the monitor size.

Depends what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can get screen height and width, and pass that value to get maximum possible size of window.
Try this:

```
int X = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN );
int Y = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN );
```

Here in `X` you will get the Width of the screen.
And in `Y` you will get the Height of the screen.

Comment: This gives the screen height. Not the max window size which is less because of the taskbar or other constraints